# How to construct the following turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

> Construct a turing machine (TM) over the alphabet {a,b,0,1,#} that reads strings of the form (ab)^n with n>0. If the string w on the tape has this structure, the TM should overwrite all letters with the character 1 and go into an accepting state and if not, the TM should overwrite all letters with the character 0 and remain in an unaccepting state.

I am not able to do the overwrite. Can someone show me how such a TM would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate pair of states, let's say $p$ and $q$, for the overwriting.

In state $p$,

- check whether to continue overwriting;
- if not, you move to a post-overwriting state;
- if yes, overwrite the cell and go to state $q$.

In state $q$, move to the next cell and go to state $p$.

Comment: I will try it, thank you